# Arc connectedness of Telophase topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In Counterexamples in Topology Book by Lynn Steen i found that Telophase topology is arc connected. How can we build an arc in this topology ?
And also could you give me an idea of how to prove that this space is sequencialy compact ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: take a look here,where i provided soe details and got a proof about why it cant be injective


   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853792/proof-about-a-topological-space-being-arc-connect

Answer (score 0):

As always, an arc is just a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $X$. An arc from $a$ to $b$ where neither of $a,b$ equals $1^*$ is obtained by taking $[0,1]\to X$, $t\mapsto a+(b-a)t$, of course. For an arc where $b=1^*$ and $a\notin \{1,1^*\}$, take an arc from $a$ to $1$ and replace $1$ with $1^*$. For an arc from $1$ to $1^*$, connect an arc from $1$ to $0$ with an arc from $0$ to $1^*$, for example.

Sequence compactness: Let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be any sequence in $X$.
If infinitely many terms of the sequence are $\ne 1^*$, then we obtain a convergent subsequence because $[0,1]$ is sequentially compact. And otherwise, i.e., if all but finitely many terms are $=1^*$, then we of course obtain a subsequence converging to $1^*$.

Comment: If we connect an arc from 1 to 0 with an arc from 0 to 1* it may no longer be one-to-one, then it will be a path but not an arc.