# Proof about a Topological space being arc connect

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

While reading a book i found a topological space described as:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be the topological space formed by adding to the
>   ordinary closed unit interval $[0,1]$ another right end point,say
>   $1*$, with the sets $(a,1)\cup${1*} as a local neighborhood basis.

Then it says that such topological space is arc connected.
I found almost exactly the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832223/arc-connectedness-of-telophase-topology) which has yet to be solve,however i'll provide some details.

> *The book itself states that since [0,1] and [0,1)$\cup${1*} are homeomorphic as subspaces,and the subspace topology on [0,1] is
>   Euclidean,X is the union of two compact subspaces and thus compact,by
>   the same reasoning it is arc connected.*

How can such argument prove me that there is a *injective* path from $1$ to $1*$? Is it possible to explicit such path?

Further details: As the book states:

> Path and arc connectednesss relate to the existence of certain
>   *continuous* functions from the unit interval into a topological
>   space.Continuous functions from the unit interval are called paths,if
>   they are *one-to-one* they are arcs.

Comment: Are you sure it says this space _is_ arc-connected?  This seems like it would be intended as an example of a space that is path-connected but _not_ arc-connected.

Comment: Could it be that the authors use the term arc-connected as synonymous to path-connected?

Comment: Unfortunatelly ,I am its on page 92 of Counterexamples in Topology by Lynn Arthur Steen,and the definition assumed there (of arc) is different from path

Comment: What is their definition of an arc?

Comment: On page 29 he shows a diagram where arc connected implies path but path does not implies arc,so i assume he's using the definition of arc by a path which is also a homeomorphism

Comment: I'll add a bit more at description

Comment: It’s a mistake in Steen & Seebach; the conclusion should be that the space is path connected. There’s at least one other that I know of, though it was also a mistake in the paper from which S&S modified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This space is not arc-connected.  Indeed, suppose $f:[0,1]\to X$ is an arc such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=1^*$.  Then $f(1/2)\in [0,1)$, and $f|_{[0,1/2]}$ is a (reparametrized) path from $1$ to $f(1/2)$ in $[0,1]$.  Thus $f([0,1/2])$ must contain all of $[f(1/2),1)$.  But by a similar argument, $f([1/2,1])$ also must contain all of $[f(1/2),1)$.  This contradicts injectivity of $f$.

Comment: Would you please elaborate why $([1/2,1])$ contains $[f(1/2), 1)$?

Comment: $f|_{[1/2,1]}$ is a path from $f(1/2)$ to $1^*$ in $[0,1)\cup\{1^*\}\cong [0,1]$.

Comment: Eric as much as I try, I still fail to see the reason :(